# JSF project stage breaks navigation

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss

im facing a strange behavior. If i change the jsf project stage in web.xml to something different than Development, it breaks the system navigation. For example: if i click on the commandButton to open a new page, the server returns a "#" symbol on the address bar next to the original URL and does not open the new page. It is strange because it only works if i set the Project Stage to Development. Im using mojarra 2.1 on Jboss EAP 6.2.0 (Jboss 7.3).

It must be some kind of bug in mojarra or Jboss. I´ve been trying all possible combinations since Jboss 7.1.

Has someone faced similar issue?

My web.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

      <display-name>SSI 2.0 - COMPRAS</display-name>

      <context-param>

            <param-name>nomesistema</param-name>

        <param-value>SSI</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>versaosistema</param-name>

        <param-value>2.0</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>modulosistema</param-name>

        <param-value>COMPRAS</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

         <param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name>

         <param-value>false</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>

        <param-value>Production</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>

        <param-value>3</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>

        <param-value>10</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>

        <param-value>server</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>

      </welcome-file-list>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>

        <param-value></param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>

        <param-value>/WEB-INF/balusc.taglib.xml</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <context-param>

        <param-name>caminhouploads</param-name>

        <param-value>/usr/compras/upload/</param-value>

      </context-param>

      <servlet>

        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        <multipart-config>

            <location>/var/tmp</location>

            <max-file-size>31457280</max-file-size>

            <max-request-size>62914560</max-request-size>

            <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>

        </multipart-config>

      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

      </servlet-mapping>

      <filter>

        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>

        <filter-class>com.ssi.compras.utils.MultipartFilter</filter-class>

        <init-param>

            <param-name>location</param-name>

            <param-value>/usr/compras/upload</param-value>

        </init-param>

      </filter>

       <filter-mapping>

         <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>

         <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

       </filter-mapping>

     </web-app>`

Login page (index.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition template="template/login.xhtml" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<ui:define name="loginsistema">
    <h:form id="formLogin">
            <div class="area-campos-login">

                <div class="area-input-100">
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="dominio" value="#{loginMB.dominio}" required="true" styleClass="select-form-login">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dominiosMB.recuperar()}" var="dominio" itemLabel="#{dominio.cnmdominio}"/>
                        <f:converter converterId="dominioConv"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>              
                </div>

                <div class="area-input-100">
                    <h:outputText value="Login:"/>
                    <h:inputText size="18" id="identificacao" styleClass="input-form-login" value="#{loginMB.usuario.cnmlogin}" required="true" onkeypress="return validaTecla(event,'mpCaracterInvalido');"></h:inputText>
                </div>

                <div class="area-input-100">
                    <h:outputText value="Senha:"/>
                    <h:inputSecret size="18" id="senha" styleClass="input-form-login" value="#{loginMB.usuario.cnmsenha}" required="true"/>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="barra-entrar">
                <div class="botoes-entrar">
                    <div class="ico-cadeado"><img src="imagens/login_cadeado.png"/></div>
                    <div class="entrar-login">
                        <h:commandLink action="#{loginMB.logar()}" id="botaoLogin">Entrar</h:commandLink>
                    </div>
                    <div class="seta-dir"></div>                
                </div>
            </div>  
        </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

The template page (template/login.xhtml)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="No-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store,No-cache,must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0,max-age=0"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
<title><h:outputText value="#{parametrosSistema.recuperaCabecalho()}"/></title>

<h:outputStylesheet name="css/geral.css" />



<style>
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    form {
        margin:0
    }

    @font-face {
     font-family: officina;
     src: url("font/officinaserifitcttbook.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
    }
    @font-face {
     font-family: officina;
     src: url("font/officinaserifitcttbook.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
    }       
    @font-face {
     font-family: officina;
     src: url("font/officinaserifitcttbook.woff") /*  */
    }       
    @font-face {
     font-family: officina;
     src: url("font/officinaserifitcttbook.otf") /*  */
    }

    .topo-login {
        width:100%;
        height:160px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c8c8c8;

        background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #eeeeee 34%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(34%,#eeeeee)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 34%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 34%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 34%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#eeeeee 34%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#eeeeee',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    }
        .logomarca-login{
            margin: 0 auto;
            width:240px;
            height:110px;
        }
        .logomarca-login img{
            margin-top:20px;
        }

    .conteudo-login {
        border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
        background: #eeeeee;

    }
        .area-campos-login {
            height: 220px;
            width: 240px;
            margin: 20px auto 0;
        }   

        .barra-entrar {
            width:100%;
            height:40px;

            background: #0085f4; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0085f4 0%, #0066cc 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0085f4), color-stop(99%,#0066cc)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #0085f4 0%,#0066cc 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #0085f4 0%,#0066cc 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #0085f4 0%,#0066cc 99%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #0085f4 0%,#0066cc 99%); /* W3C */
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0085f4', endColorstr='#0066cc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
        }

        .botoes-entrar {
            width:240px;
            margin:0 auto;
            font-family: officina;
            color:#fff;
        }
        .ico-cadeado {
            width:120px;
            float:left;
        }
        .ico-cadeado img{
            margin-top:-2px;
        }           
        .entrar-login {
            width:100px;
            text-align:right;
            float:left;
            margin-top: 6px;
        }
        .entrar-login a {
            color: #FFFFFF !important;
            font-family: officina;
            font-size: 1.7em;
        }           


    .rodape-login {
        width:100%;
        height: 70px;
        position: relative;

        background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    }
        .logomarca-vivo-login {
            float:right;
            margin-right:20%;
        }
        .logomarca-telefonica-login {
            float:left;
            margin-left:20%;
        }

    .seta-dir {
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background: url('imagens/setas.png') no-repeat 0 5px;
        float:left;
        margin-top: 6px;
    }

    .label {
        font-size:0.9em;
        color:#797979;
        margin-right:26px;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

</style>

</h:head>
<h:body>

<div id="divContent">

    <div class="topo-login">
        <div class="logomarca-login">
            <img src="imagens/login_logo.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudo-login">
        <ui:insert name="loginsistema"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="rodape-login">
        <div class="logomarca-telefonica-login">
            <img src="imagens/rodape_telefonica.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="logomarca-vivo-login">
            <img src="imagens/rodape_vivo.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>    

<a4j:outputPanel id="panelerrologin">
    <h:panelGroup id="pgexibeerrologin" rendered="#{loginMB.flagerroautenticacao}" showWhenRendered="#{loginMB.flagerroautenticacao}" layout="block" styleClass="erro">
        <div class="erro-simbolo"/>
        <h:outputText value="Autenticação falhou !" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</a4j:outputPanel>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    var janela = $(window).height();
    $('.conteudo-login').css('height',janela-235+'px');

    });

</script>

  </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any difference in JS console or HTTP monitor? Perhaps `jsf.js` failed to load? By the way, using POST for page-to-page navigation is bad.

Comment: Hi BalusC.. thanks for the reply. I´m using the button to return a reference to a new page if the user authenticates OK. That´s why I need do this post navigation - let me know if there´s a better way of doing this, please.    On the JS console (Firefox) im able to see these warning:    **ReferenceError: $ is not defined**   And just after the button click, this one below:  **ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined**  Im going to put my web.xml on the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, `jsf.js` clearly failed to load. You're the only one who can figure out the why as you've the runtime environment right in your front. As hinted, check HTTP monitor as well.

Comment: Thanks.. I think this is going to be kind of troublesome. Im about to deploy a project in production environment. Do you know if there´s any hassle going production with this setting in "Development"?

Comment: Have you tried removing the MultipartFilter mapping? That url-pattern seems fishy.

Comment: Hi Mabi.. Actually, im having this problem for months... I´ve been googling for a solution without success. These MultipartFilter lines, were added a couple of weeks ago. But thanks anyway...

Comment: Im going to add my xhtml template and the login page... I´d be glad If somebody figure this one out. its driving me crazy.. :(

Comment: @Márcio -try manually injecting the script library `<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>`

Comment: @kolossus thanks for the answer. I´ve tried putting this code into <h:head> tags and inside the main login form, without success... :(

Comment: the strange thing is.. all the system works pretty nice in Development and only in Development stage.But im worried if Im going to have performance issues keeping this Stage setted.

Comment: @Márcio Try the most recent version of Mojarra 2.1

Comment: Thanks @kolossus.. Going to download the latest tomorrow and give it a try..

Comment: Tried with the latest mojarra 2.1.27 with no luck at all

Comment: Going to create a simple test project and see what happens

Comment: People, i have solved the issue. Actually i dont know why, but it seems a bug with Richfaces 4.2.2 library. I updated to 4.3.4 and tried the "Production" stage and everything worked fine. I really dont know why, going to investigate further after going production next week. Thanks !!